# Could not change SVG element background in jsPDF

Tags: svg, jspdf

I'm using jspdf (2.3.1) library. When I try to change svg element background color using addSvgAsImage () method, background color is not changed and it always display black color background. Could anybody help with this.

[image]

```
exportPdf() {  
    const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a3');       
    doc.addSvgAsImage('<svg width="200" height="200" style="background-color: red"><polygon 
     points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill- 
     rule:evenodd;"/></svg>', 10, 50, 200 ,200);                 
     doc.html(document.getElementById("exportPage"), {callback: function (doc) {
    doc.save('test.pdf');
  },x: 10, y: 250});    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS property `background-color` is really an HTML thing. It's quite possible jsPDF's SVG parser doesn't support that. Try replacing it with a rectangle instead.

```
exportPdf() {  
    const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a3');       
    doc.addSvgAsImage('<svg width="200" height="200"><rect width="200" height="200" fill="red"/><polygon 
     points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill- 
     rule:evenodd;"/></svg>', 10, 50, 200 ,200);                 
     doc.html(document.getElementById("exportPage"), {callback: function (doc) {
    doc.save('test.pdf');
  },x: 10, y: 250});    
}
```